# Problem with setting up Mingw w64 for C++. Possible conflict with existing Anaconda/Jupyter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, mingw-w64

While I am setting up MinGW-W64 (from sourceforge) exe file (for Windows 10) for C++, it shows a message that it was not downloaded correctly. My best guess is that I have a Anaconda/Jupyter setup having MinGW-W64, and it is making all the fuss. How to set it up for both C++ (VS Code / Code lite) and Python/Jupyter/Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't mix versions in environment variables like `PATH`.

Maybe your download *was* bad?

Or you may have an antivirus software preventing the installation...

You could try a standalone MinGW-w64 build from https://winlibs.com/, which doesn't requite installation - just extract the archive and point VSCode to it.